# How to load custom content to jquery dialog from html table

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a list of images presented in a `table` format with an update option to edit the **image/description** in a `dialog box`.

I have implemented a javascript function `loadDialog` to dynamically pass the `id` to the `dialog`.

However, the editor complains that `id` is not recognized in the line below:

```
$(this).load("@Url.Action("UpdateProjectImageDetail", new { ProjectId = id})") ;
```

Following are the script and html files.

```
$(function(){
    $('#OpenImgDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Add/Update Image',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});


function loadDialog(id) {
    var Pid = id;
    $("#OpenImgDialog").dialog({
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var Pid = id;
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("UpdateProjectImageDetail", new { ProjectId = id})") ;
            }
    });
    $('#OpenImgDialog').dialog('open');
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Image
    </th>
    <th>
        Description
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Images) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src ="@item.ImageString" width="200" height="100" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="UpdateImage" href="#" onclick="loadDialog(@item.Id)">Edit</a>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**How can I pass arguments from javascript to Url.Action?**

Or is there a better approach to solving this problem?

Any demo/reference/solution will be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appologies I think I know what you are after.
in the

```
$(this).load("@Url.Action("UpdateProjectImageDetail", new { ProjectId = id})") ;
```

the

```
@Url.Action("UpdateProjectImageDetail", new { ProjectId = id})
```

is running server side you need to pass in the id from the client to the server. which meands it should look something like this

```
function loadDialog(id) {
    var Pid = id;
    $("#OpenImgDialog").dialog({
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var Pid = id;
            var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateProjectImageDetail")?ProjectId=' + id;
            $(this).load(url) ;
            }
    });
    $('#OpenImgDialog').dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: Delete option works fine. I have problems sending the id (dynamically) to the Edit function using Html.ActionLink

Answer (score 0):

@Url.Action() is server side code, so you can't pass a client side (js) variable to it.

Without looking too closely, you could probably do something like:

```
$(this).load("@Url.Action(...)" + "?ProjectId=" + id);
```

There's probably a more elegant solution, but that's all I have time for right now... ;)